# Vue multiple scoped style tags

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a component that I want to re-use but with a completely different style for each usage.
The idea is to keep the template and script but have a different look based on some condition, hence avoid duplicating the component.
e.g.

```
<template>
  <div class="some-class">
  ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
...
</script>

<style scoped>
  .some-class {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<style scoped>
  .some-class {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Instead of creating two different scoped style. you can use `:class` to dynamically bind the styles based on the condition.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've thought about this but it requires using different classes. My intention is to dynamically apply rules on the same class.  Perhaps my question was not clear enough, my apologies.  I've updated my question to elaborate.

Comment: As per my understanding I added an answer. Please let me know if that will work as per your expectation or any further changes required.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating two different scoped style. you can use :class to dynamically bind the styles based on the condition.

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data:{
    lookA: false,
    lookB: false
  }
});
```

```css
.lookA{
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}

.lookB {
  background: green;
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label for="a">Change color for look A : </label><input type="checkbox" v-model="lookA" id="a"><br>
  <label for="b">Change colors for look B : </label><input type="checkbox" v-model="lookB" id="b">
  <br><br>
  <div v-bind:class="{'lookA': lookA, 'lookB': lookB}">
    Welcome!
  </div>
</div>
```